# Best practice to handle IO Exceptions while coping directory(s) and file(s)?

Tags: java, file, inputstream, outputstream, ioexception

Sample code is below.  It will copy the target files and directory from one location to another.  What's considered best practice for handling IO Exceptions while coping files across a network?

I used printStackTrace() but feel like this is just a place holder for a better solution.  Is logging the answer and should there be another step beyond logging to actually "handle" an error?

Thank you for you feedback.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
   This is a test program to copy a directory(s) & file(s) from one location to another.
*/

public class CopyTest{

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      //Declarations 
      String sourcePath = "I:\\MB\\PO"; 
      String destPath = "C:\\testPO\\";  
      System.out.println("Source path:  " + sourcePath);  
      System.out.println("Destination path:  " + destPath);  
      File source = new File(sourcePath);  
      File dest = new File(destPath);  

      //Process
      //Call to method copyUsingStream
      long start = System.nanoTime(); //start recording how much time the copy takes.
      copyUsingStream(source, dest);  //method to copy the directory/files.
      System.out.println("Time taken to copy the file: "+(System.nanoTime() -start) + " nanoseconds");

   } //end main method

   /**
      The copyUsingStream method is a recursive method to copy folders and files from one location to another.
   */

   private static void copyUsingStream(File source, File dest) {   

      if (!source.isDirectory()){ 
         // If source is a file -> copy it to the new folder
         InputStream inStream = null;
         OutputStream outStream = null;
         try {
            inStream = new FileInputStream(source);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
               outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
         } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
         } finally {
            try{
               inStream.close();
               outStream.close();
               System.out.println("File copied from " + source + " to " + dest + "successfully");
            } catch(IOException ioe2) {
               ioe2.printStackTrace();
            }
         } 
      } else {

         //If a directory -> create the directory inside the new destination
         //List all contents

         if (!dest.exists()) {
            dest.mkdir();
            System.out.println("Directory copied from " + source + " to " + dest + "successfully");
         }

         String folder_contents[] = source.list();

         for (String file : folder_contents) {

            File srcFile = new File(source, file);
            File destFile = new File(dest, file);

            copyUsingStream(srcFile, destFile);

         }

      }

   } //end method copyUsingStream

} //end class CopyTest
```

Method without the catches:

```
   private static void copyUsingStream(File source, File dest) throws IOException {   

      if (!source.isDirectory()){ 
         // If source is a file -> copy it to the new folder
         InputStream inStream = null;
         OutputStream outStream = null;
         try {
            inStream = new FileInputStream(source);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
               outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
         } finally {
               inStream.close();
               outStream.close();
               System.out.println("File copied from " + source + " to " + dest + "successfully");
         } 
      } else {

         //If a directory -> create the directory inside the new destination
         //List all contents

         if (!dest.exists()) {
            dest.mkdir();
            System.out.println("Directory copied from " + source + " to " + dest + "successfully");
         }

         String folder_contents[] = source.list();

         for (String file : folder_contents) {

            File srcFile = new File(source, file);
            File destFile = new File(dest, file);

            copyUsingStream(srcFile, destFile);

         }

      }

   } //end method copyUsingStream
```

Comment: Rather than using a stream to copy things around, you could just use `java.nio`'s `Files.copy` which takes two `Path` objects.  You can instantiate `Path` objects using `Filesystems.getDefault().getPath("DirectoryNameHere", "FileNameHere");`

Comment: Hi Powerlord, Thanks for the feedback.  I should have clarified that I used steam just for the academic purpose of working with it.   I definitely did see in my research that nio's file.copy is the cleaner and "better" way to accomplish this action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends highly on your application.

Applications that continue running anyway (e.g. web servers, daemons and batch processors) do usually log such errors in a file together with timestamp, thread ID and possibly other helpful information.

I had very good experience with a combination of two log files.

1. `myapp.log` receives only important messages, usually warnings and errors. This file is for the regular user and system operator.
2. `debug.log` is for the developer. It provides debug messages from the time before an error occurred, but no messages as long everything works fine. To enable this, a memory buffer is required.

If you are interested in that buffer, you may take a look at http://stefanfrings.de/bfUtilities/index.html . The website is german but the library and it's documentation is english.

On a desktop GUI application, when an error aborts the requested operation, it might be nice to show a short error messages in a popup window, and hide the details (stack trace) in an expandable box. Don't forget to tell the user clearly what operation failed. The exception itself may be clear enough to you developer but regular users expect a less technical text. For example: "Loading weather info from service weather.com failed: Connection failed", followed by the stack trace.

For console applications that stop immediately, I prefer so see the stack trace directly on screen as written by `printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Thanks Stefan.  This will end up as a test bed to create a stand alone GUI utility.

Answer (score 0):

As Stefan said, it depends on the application.

A good rule of thumb is:  Don’t catch an exception unless you are prepared to take a specific action, beyond printing or logging it, or there is no caller to whom you can propagate it.

If you have a general method for copying a file, that method should not make assumptions about why it’s being called.  Its job is to copy a file.  It should return only if it succeeds in that task.  If it does not succeed, it should throw an exception rather than returning.

So for a general copying method, you would want to add `throws IOException` to the method signature, and have zero try/catch blocks in the method itself.  This lets the callers decide how to handle a failure.  A GUI application might display an error dialog.  A service might just log the exception and try again later.

You yourself should only catch and log an exception at the highest possible level.  A GUI application would log it right before displaying the error dialog.  (You might also want to include the text of the stack trace in the dialog, in an expandable “Show details” section.)  A service might have a main loop or main execution method, where there is no higher caller to whom the exception can be propagated, so there is nothing to do but log it.

Comment: Thank Stefan.  I reworked the method to take the catches out and added the throws IOException to the method header.  Are there any other changes that should be made to this method itself related to handling the exception later?

Comment: Not really.  Javadoc is always nice.  But in terms of functionality, adding a `throws` clause means error handling is up to the caller and not that method’s responsibility, so there isn’t any more to do.